# onclick event handler in javascript code, not html tag

Tags: javascript, event-handling

when trying to ensure my webpage is using unobtrusive javascript I cant seem to get the onclick event to work in my javascript, it only works as an event in the html tag. here is the code

```
var dow = document.getElementById("dowDiv");
dow.onclick=function () {}
```

any reason that this isnt working for me? as all the answers i can find say this is the way to do it, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the HTML that has the `dowDiv` id?

Comment: Inspect it in console. The error might be there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons based on the information provided.

Most likely, the event function code is being attached before the DOM has finished loading.

Alternatively, you might be using a browser which doesn't support onclick (though this is unlikely!). To guarantee it will work, you can use fallbacks for the main routes of attaching an event:

```
if (dow.addEventListener) {
  dow.addEventListener('click', thefunction, false);
} else if (dow.attachEvent) {
  dow.attachEvent('onclick', thefunction);
} else {
  dow.onclick = thefunction; 
}
```

Comment: it was the first answer, thank you! evidentially im a bit of a novice!

Comment: It's no problem, I can't think of the number of times I've done the same thing and spent some time scratching my head over why my code wasn't being called!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you only have one element with the id `dowDiv`. If you have z-index's on elements and something is over the div it might be blocking the click event on the div.

```js
var dow = document.getElementById("dowDiv");
var out = document.getElementById("out");
var clickCount = 0;
dow.onclick = function() {
  clickCount += 1;
  out.innerHTML = clickCount
}
```

```html
<div id="dowDiv">Hello onclick <span id="out"></span>!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve a simple o'clock function.

Make you include jQuery BEFORE you reference your .js file:

```
<script src="path/to/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="file.js></script>
```

With jQuery you can say

```
$('#dowDIV').click(function(){
   Do stuff here;
})
```