# Bind an html event to a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How do I bind an html event such as `onclick` to a function `myFunc(e){}`?

I do not want to use `document.getElementByClass` or `Id`.

I do not want use jQuery.

Comment: You want your click to trigger a function?

Comment: Yes. Click would be great.  Just curious about the (e) event and binding somehow.

Comment: There are a lot of SO where you can get what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick event handler in javascript code, not html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182967/onclick-event-handler-in-javascript-code-not-html-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){alert("you clicked on the page")})
```

This adds an event listener to the body tag. Once you click on the page, it will fire the alert function.

You can get the elements by either class name, id and/or tag name:

```
document.getElementById('someId')
document.getElementsByClassName('someClassName')  
document.getElementsByTagName('body')
```

Keep in mind, the "getElementsByClassName" and "getElementsByTagName" return arrays, so you might want to add the index like this

```
getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
document.getElementsByClassName('someClassName')[1]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's still the 1990s where you are and jQuery hasn't been invented, then sure:

```
<div onclick="myFunc">
</div>
```

Comment: Lol.  Thanks for the help

Comment: It's the simplest thing that works without jQuery. Don't knock it!

Answer (score 0):

First you must find the element on the page, for example `var element = document.getElementById('clickme')`, then you must add a listener to the click event `element.addEventListener('click',function)`